# Values of parameter $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ that make a rational function decreasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

For $p \in (0,1]$, an integer $n \geq 2$ and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, I want to show that  $$\frac{p (1- \epsilon p)^{n-1}}{1- (1-p)^n}$$ is a decreasing function of $p$ for $\epsilon > g(n)$ for some function $g()$ and in particular

$$\frac{p (1- \epsilon p)^{n-1}}{1- (1-p)^n} \geq (1-\epsilon)^{n-1}$$ for all $\epsilon > g(n)$ with equality at $p=1$. I tried to show that the derivative with respect to p is negative, however without success. Does anyone have any idea how to show this otherwise?

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, I could not show the derivative with respect to p to be negative, that's why the question!

Comment: Are you sure? I would rather guess the function is decreasing for some $\epsilon> g(n)$, for some $g()$, but I am curious to know how you got to your conclusion, can you please tell me?

Comment: I thought I was getting turned around, but why don't you try this: Take $n=3$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$ and plot the expression on $(0,1]$.  Actually the singularity at $p=0$ is removable, but in any case I get the curve is increasing rather than decreasing (as a function of $p$).

Comment: Note that with those choices of $n,\epsilon$ the value as $p$ tends to zero is one-third, but the value at $p=1$ is $0.81$.  So the expression is clearly not *decreasing* on $(0,1]$.

Comment: yeah, at $\epsilon=0.1$ it is indeed an increasing function, that's why I said that we'd perhaps need $\epsilon > g(n)$ for some $g()$ to have the function decrease with $p$. For example, set $\epsilon=0.5$ (or any value greater than $0.5$ and $n=3$ as before), then the curve is decreasing as a function of $p$..I'm unable to explicitly write down the form of $g()$ for which the function becomes decreasing.

Comment: I believe I have a complete solution based on taking the derivative.  Just need to find time to get it posted.

Comment: That'd be great @hardmath, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

$$ \frac{p (1- \epsilon p)^{n-1}}{1- (1-p)^n} $$

is well-defined for $p \in (0,1]$, integer $n \ge 2$ and $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$.

We take as the problem to identify for which values of $\epsilon$ the expression is monotone decreasing.  As Comments on the the Question demonstrate, the behavior of the expression for varying $\epsilon$ values depends on $n$, with some combinations of values producing monotonic decreases and others not.

Note that while the expression as written is undefined for $p=0$, both numerator and denominator tend to zero.  Further, an application of l'Hôpital's Rule shows that $\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{p}$ tends to $n$ as $p\to 0^+$, so the expression above tends to $1/n$ "at" $p=0$.

Thus a necessary condition for this expression to be a decreasing function of $p$ on $(0,1]$ is that:

$$ \frac{1}{n} \ge (1-\epsilon)^{n-1} $$

Solving more explicitly for $\epsilon$ produces the following necessary condition:

$$ \epsilon \ge 1 - \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}} $$

The rest of our post provides a sufficient condition, and we establish this by taking the derivative and invoking Descartes Rule of Signs.

For convenience we rewrite the expression at top in terms of $q = 1 - p$, so that our inquiry is about whether:

$$ F(q) \equiv \frac{(1-q)(1 - \epsilon(1-q))^{n-1}}{1-q^n} $$

is *increasing* as a function of $q$ on $[0,1)$.

Cancelling $1-q$ from numerator and denominator simplifies $F(q)$ and allows us to evaluate $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ without recourse to l'Hôpital's Rule:

$$ F(q) = \frac{(\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-1}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k} $$

This function is continuous on $[0,1]$ and by inspection $F(0)=(1-\epsilon)^{n-1}$ and $F(1)=1/n$.  Our previous observation about the necessary condition is now reframed as a requirement for *increasing*, $F(0) \le F(1)$.

The derivative with respect to $q$ is a straightforward application of the quotient rule:

$$ \begin{align*} F'(q)
&= \frac{(n-1)\epsilon(\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k 
 - (\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k q^{k-1}}{\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \right)^2} \\
&= \frac{(\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-2}
 \left[ (n-1)\epsilon\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k 
\; - \; (\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (k+1) q^k \right]}{\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \right)^2} \\
&= \frac{(\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-2}
 \left[ (n-1)\epsilon - 1 +\epsilon
+ \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} ((n-1)\epsilon - (1 - \epsilon)(k+1) - \epsilon k)  q^k \right)
+ (n-1)\epsilon q^{n-1} - (n-1)\epsilon q^{n-1} \right]}{\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \right)^2} \\
&= \frac{(\epsilon q + 1 -\epsilon)^{n-2}
 \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (n\epsilon-1-k) q^k \right]}{\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \right)^2}
\end{align*} $$

Because the base factor in the numerator $\epsilon q + (1-\epsilon)$ is positive and the denominator is the square of a positive term, the sign of derivative $F'(q)$ is determined by the sign of the degree $n-2$ polynomial factor in the numerator:

$$ P(q) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (n\epsilon-1-k) q^k $$

Plainly $F(q)$ is not constant on $[0,1]$ and hence is increasing there if and only if $P(q) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$.  The coefficients of $P(q)$ are monotone decreasing, so by Descartes Rule of Signs $P(q)$ can have at most one positive real root.

Take note of these computations:

$$ \begin{align*} 
P(0) &= n\epsilon - 1 \\
P(1) &= (n-1)(n\epsilon - 1) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} k \\
     &= (n-1)\left( n\epsilon - 1 - \frac{n-2}{2} \right) \\
     &= (n-1)\left( n\epsilon - \frac{n}{2} \right) 
\end{align*}$$

Since $P(1) \ge 0 \iff \epsilon \ge 1/2$, recalling $n \ge 2$, it follows that $\epsilon \ge 1/2$ is both a necessary and sufficient condition for $F(q)$ to be increasing on $[0,1]$ and correspondingly for the original expression to be decreasing on $(0,1]$ as a function of $p$.

Comment: I wrote it up quickly enough that there needs to be some checking of my algebra.